# Vue :click is being triggered automatically inside v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have v-for looping and elements inside it have :click calling a function. That function is being triggered automatically on every single element on page load!

```
<li v-if="itemSaved.length > 0" v-for="(item, index) in items" class="list-group-item">
   <div class="pull-right m-l">
     <i v-if="itemSaved[index] == 'not saved'" class="icon-plus" :click="addItem(item.id)"></i>
     <i v-else class="icon-check" :click="removeItem(item.id)"></i>
   </div>
</li>



export default {
 data: () => ({
  itemSaved: [{"id":1, "name":"Jim"},{"id":2, "name":"Max"}]
}),
methods: {

  addItem: function(id){
    console.log('add item ' + id)
  }, 
  removeItem: function(id){
    console.log('remove item ' + id)
  }
}
}
```

Basically I get a list of `add item 1` and `add item 2` in the console log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be:

```
@click="removeItem(item.id)"
```

Not:

```
:click="removeItem(item.id)"
```

---

When you have `:click="removeItem(item.id)"` you are actually binding the result of the `removeItem(item.id)` method call to the `click` property. Which is why the method executes "automatically".

`@click="handler"` [is a shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand) to `v-on:click="handler"` - the [**event handling directive**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

`:click="handler"` [is a shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) to `v-bind:click="handler"`, the [**property binding directive**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props).